# Why some IDEs (Intellij/Android Studio) has its vertical line as default?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Does anyone know the reason why the developers of some IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio) implement vertical line in the middle of the editor view by default.
Some of my friends told me it is frustrating to have this vertical line since he writes code on average exceeds the line. (oh by the way i love IntelliJ, no offense)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some coding standards enforce the maximum line length on the code and this indent guide helps you to understand where the code will be wrapped by the IDE formatter if you have configured the code style settings to wrap at the specified margin.

You can either change the indent margin in the IDE code style settings or disable it completely if you don't want to enforce any limits (set the hard wrap to 0):

[image: wrap]